# Can I install Exchange 2007 in an environment w/ 32-bit Domain Controller computers?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2007, 64-bit

I've got 2 64-bit servers for the Mail Box and Client Access, but my domain controller is 32-bit. Can I install Exchange 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Exchange Server itself is not supported on 32-bit versions of Windows, but your DC/s do not need to be 64-bit. The data stored in Active Directory is not fundamentally different between 32- and 64-bit editions of Windows.

Comment: Great! Now, how should I perform setup /prepareschema on it? It outputs The image file G:\setup.com is valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine, which means can't run on non-64-bit machines.

Comment: You can run the commands from the 64-bit server which you are going to install Exchange on. The schema changes will be done on the DC, but that doesn't mean you need to run setup.com on the DC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of the commands should be run from the 64 bit system that you are installing exchange on.  You must be a member of the Schema Admins group as well as the Exchange Admins group to do the AD prep work.  If you are running the schema dn forest updates manaully they still need to be run from the exchange server and you still need the appropriate permissions to modify AD